# pendrive shown correctly in gparted but not in df -h

Tags: usb, mount, gparted, fstab

my pendrive (cruzer/sandisk 4GB) is recognized correctly by `gparted` but it is not listed in `df -h`. It was working fine just few hours ago, I tried rebooting but it doesn't show anymore. on the other side, I have managed to copy to it an iso-image with `dd`, referring to it with the name listed in `gparted`: `/dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to list all available drives

Use `sudo fdisk -l` to show all available partitions (mounted or not).

`df -h` will only show disks that are mounted. Also a simple `mount` without any options, will show all mounted drives (without actually mounting anything btw).